# How to use substring in rawQuery android

Tags: android, database

Hi I'm trying to use substring in my query but I'm having this error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: SUBSTRING (code 1)
```

i want to get the last 7 characters from each data result in my query. I'm using Cursor as well.
here is my code

```
public Cursor DistinctResult() {
    return this.myDataBase.rawQuery("select DISTINCT SUBSTRING("+KEY_LOCATION+",-7) from "+TBL, null);
}
```

What is the possible problem to it? is there any other option to do this? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no such function: SUBSTRING (code 1)` means that SUBSTRING function is not available in sqlite and that should be **SUBSTR()**

Just change **`SUBSTRING`**  to **`SUBSTR`** that should help you

AND Please read this link for sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Answer (score 1):

> The `substr(X,Y,Z)` function returns a substring of input string X that
>   begins with the Y-th character and which is Z characters long. If Z is
>   omitted then `substr(X,Y)` returns all characters

For more details:
[sqlite_corefunc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)